# On WindowsPhone for retrieving webservice data, which is applicable whether JSON or xml

Tags: json, xml-parsing, windows-phone

I used xml services for post and retrieving data from webservices. I dont know about JSON parsing, whether JSON is easy than xml.

Answer (score 0):

That depends, do you plan on supporting other platforms?

The .Net based platforms have more than ample resources for easily consuming services that are hosted with a variety of serialization methods (and many other variances). If you only plan on supporting Windows Phone or other .Net based platforms than you may find that XML Serialization is easy and can stick with it. When you start to consider other platforms then you may find that Xml serialization can at times be a pain and JSON is the preferred way.

If you want to go with JSON parsing in addition to the JSON serializer that comes with the .Net platforms you may also want to check out [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (which is much more flexible than what comes with the .Net libraries) and [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for consuming REST based services with JSON serialization.